# Get the result of a list into one line

Tags: javascript

I have an html code like this

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name"> product 1: </span>
        <span class="value"> clothes</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name"> product 2: </span>
        <span class="value"> glasses </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name"> product 3: </span>
        <span class="value"> bread </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name"> product 4: </span>
        <span class="value"> fruits </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

inside every div.item.type exist every time 2 spans with the same name classes name and value. I would like to take the innerText but some times the html code doesn't have all products.

Example:

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name"> product 1: </span>
        <span class="value"> clothes</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name"> product 3: </span>
        <span class="value"> bread </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name"> product 4: </span>
        <span class="value"> fruits </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In order to take them all I will made something like this:

```
product_1_name = document.querySelectorAll('div.products div.item.type span.name'>[0].innerText
product_1_value = document.querySelectorAll('div.products div.item.type span.value'>[0].innerText
product_2_name = document.querySelectorAll('div.products div.item.type span.name'>[1].innerText
product_2_value = document.querySelectorAll('div.products div.item.type span.value'>[1].innerText
product_3_name = document.querySelectorAll('div.products div.item.type span.name'>[2].innerText
product_3_value = document.querySelectorAll('div.products div.item.type span.value'>[2].innerText
product_4_name = document.querySelectorAll('div.products div.item.type span.name'>[3].innerText
product_4_value = document.querySelectorAll('div.products div.item.type span.value'>[3].innerText
```

but if I use it in the second example it will not give the right results

Is there any js query which could give a result like this?

for name class have a result like this: `product1,product3,product4`

for value class have a result like this: `clothes,bread,fruits`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to do it in a similar way to this one:

```js
let products = {};

document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach((item) => {
 products[item.querySelector('.name').innerText] = item.querySelector('.value').innerText;
});

console.log(products);
```

```html
<div class="products">
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name"> product 1: </span>
        <span class="value"> clothes</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name"> product 3: </span>
        <span class="value"> bread </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name"> product 4: </span>
        <span class="value"> fruits </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by using:

```
window.document.getElementsByClassName
```

Example

```
window.document.getElementsByClassName("name");   //returns a collections
window.document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerText; //product 1
window.document.getElementsByClassName("name")[1].innerText; //product 2
window.document.getElementsByClassName("value")[0].innerText; //clothes
```

Alternatively you can do it with window.document.querySelectorAll

```
window.document.querySelectorAll(".name"); //collection of all elts with class name.
window.document.querySelectorAll(".value"); //colllection of all elts with class value.
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getParsedString(nodeList) {
  var arr = Array.from(nodeList, function(el) {
    return el.textContent.replace(/^\s*|\s*$|[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/g, ""); // Remove space at the beginning and at the end, remove chars that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _ or -
  });
  return arr.join(",");
}

var names = getParsedString(document.querySelectorAll(".products .name"));
var values = getParsedString(document.querySelectorAll(".products .value"));

console.log(names);
console.log(values);
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="item type">
    <span class="name"> product 1: </span>
    <span class="value"> clothes</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item type">
    <span class="name"> product 3: </span>
    <span class="value"> bread </span>
  </div>
  <div class="item type">
    <span class="name"> product 4: </span>
    <span class="value"> fruits </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say to search by JavaScript all the inner text inside the tags with class = 'name' to get a list of the product's name and after implode this list into a string.

And the same, also, for the value's name: Get all the inner text inside the tags with class = 'value' to get a list of the product's value and after implode this list into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Working demo at jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9tw5Lopx/1/

Try out this way

```
var arrName = new Array();
var arrValue = new Array();
//here i am considering "item type" is class 
// if both are class than use one of them only 
var container=document.getElementsByClassName('item type"');
for(var i=0;i< container.lenght;i++)
{
  var spanArray=container[i].getElementsByTagName('span');
  for(var s=0;s<spanArray.length;s++){
  {
    if(element.classList.contains('name'))
      arrName.push(span[s].innerHTML]);
    else 
     arrValue.push(span[s].innerHTML]);
  }
}
var str="";
for(var j=0;j< arrName;j++)
  str += arrName[j] + ":" + arrValue[j] + "<br/>";
document.getElementsById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 
        document.getElementsByClassName('item type"');
```

Comment: There is a shorter way to do this, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/9tw5Lopx/.

Comment: @PeterLeger - every one here provided their solution .. i provided mine ...i dont know that short method that means i get -1

Comment: @PeterLeger - what about answer given by this guy "Ricard Espinàs Llovet"...that also deserve -1 or "Mosè Raguzzini" jquery way which is not requested...

Comment: The -1 for me means: "It's too much. There is a shorter way to do it"

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($('.products .item .name').text().split(": ").join(','));
console.log($('.products .item .value').text().split(" ").join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products">
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name">product 1: </span>
        <span class="value">clothes </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name">product 3: </span>
        <span class="value">bread </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item type">
        <span class="name">product 4: </span>
        <span class="value">fruits </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its juqery ...i think OP need in pure html way

Comment: He didn't mention any contraints so I posted the simplest solution,

Comment: Check it taggd under javascript not jquery

Comment: jQuery is actually javascript...there are plenty of answers in pure javascript, this is also javascript.